# System of Equation Solver? Online

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, wolfram-alpha

What site do people use to solve systems of equations with algebraic coefficients. I.E I know wolfram solves

$$
x+y=2,~~y-3x=1
$$
but are there sites that let you put unknown constants?
$$
x+c_1y=2,~~y-c_2x=c_3.
$$

EDIT : (all helpful answers and I would up vote if I could!) Note I tried this in wolfram and it didn't work (this is the beast I wanted solved for me ):

solve v_1=A+B- (c_5 a / c_1(c_8+ c_3c_5/c_1 )),   v_2=Ae^{r_1 h }+Be^{r_2 h}-  (c_5 a / c_1(c_8+ c_3c_5/c_1 )),  x_1=b-(1/c_1)(A(c_2+c_3/r_1)+B(c_2+c_3/r_2)), x_2=b+ah-(1/c_1)(Ae^{r_1 h}(c_2+c_3/r_1)+Be^{r_2 h}(c_2+c_3/r_2)),   for a, b, A, B

Comment: You can ask Wolfram to solve for particular set of variables.

Comment: @user no their constants I just dont have their specific numerical value.

Comment: wolfram can do it as already as been said

Comment: [Your example in WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x+%2B+c_1+y+%3D+2%2C+y+-+c_2+x+%3D+c_3+for+x%2C+y)

Comment: Ahhh easy :) thanks

Comment: @Tortar How come wolfram wont accept what I gave it?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask Wolfram Alpha

```
solve x+c_1y=2, y-c_2x=c_3 for x,y
```

[you get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%2Bc_1y%3D2%2C%20y-c_2x%3Dc_3%20for%20x%2Cy)

- $x = \dfrac{2 - c_1 c_3}{c_1 c_2 + 1}$ and $y = \dfrac{2 c_2 + c_3}{c_1 c_2 + 1}$ and $c_1 c_2 + 1\not=0$
- $y = -\dfrac {c_3}{x - 2}$ and $2 c_2 + c_3 = 0$ and $c_3 \not=0$ and $c_1 = \dfrac2{c_3}$

I suspect you may looking for the first of these, though the second deals with the $c_1 c_2+1=0$ situation.

For more complicated situations, you may want to invest in a computer algebra system

Comment: Yeah because - see my edit, its not working for the system I wrote... :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Graphically you can do this on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and get a sliding bar to manipulate the variables. [Here are your equations.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxmvoraei3)

Comment: Not graphically, sorry An exact solver for x and y in terms of $c_1,c_2,c_3$

Comment: Clearly Im not asking for this specific case, I have a more convoluted thing in mind.